# Concatenating duplicate columns by name within a single Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have one hot encoded categories from one column into multiple columns of True/False values. In the original format, the categories appear in a single 'Categories' column as e.g [ENTERTAINMENT, GAME_ARCADE]. I split on the ',', store the results in a set and then match to the original column. Here is the code used to identify the following columns:

```
#Determine the unique categories
def cat_split(df):
    genres = set()
    for c in df.category:
        genres.update(g for g in c.split(','))
    genres = sorted(genres)
    return genres

#Makes a column for each category/genre
def cat_col(genres, df):
    for genre in genres:
        df[genre] = [genre in cat.split(',') for cat in df.category]
    return df
```

Unsurprisingly, this has created duplicate columns of [ENTERTAINMENT and ENTERTAINMENT]. I was hoping to merely strip the '[' and ']' and then merge the columns with:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
```

However, this wreaks havoc with another datetime column, turning all values to 1970-01-01 for some reason.

---

I feel like the solution is rather obvious, but I can't figure it out. Is there a way to concatenate columns of the same name (e.g ENTERTAINMENT) so that all True values are retained?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
def cat_col(genres, df):
    for genre in genres:
        df[genre] = [genre in cat.split(',') for cat in df.category]
    return df
```

try:

```
def cat_col(genres, df):
    for genre in list(set(genres)):
        df[genre] = [genre in cat.split(',') for cat in df.category]
    return df
```

Comment: Returns: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Although I am inclined to solve the problem at the creation of the columns, rather than clean it up afterwards.

Comment: sorry, right - I was modifying rows, not columns - I think the above should do the trick

Comment: I'm afraid not, same problem as before.